# ZF2 forward email (Zend\Mail\Storage\Message)

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2

I need to forward email using Zend Framework 2.

I have tried

```
//$message - Zend\Mail\Storage\Message
$message->to = 'lala@example.com';
$transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
$transport->send($message);
```

but `$transport->send()` only accepts `Zend\Mail\Message`

Anyone knows the way to forward without creating new `Zend\Mail\Message`?

Comment: Which specific ZF version are you using, and which storage backend did the existing Message come from?  It looks like you might be able to call `getContent` and `getMessage` on it and pass them to `setHeaders` and `setBody` on the new message, but that's going to depend on what type of data the old Message returns.

Comment: @Charles ty for your suggestions. My zend version is 2.2.4. I am getting messages using IMAP.

Comment: @StephanWeinhold, here Zend Framework 2 is specified, which was not specified in the question marked as duplicate.

Comment: @lajos-arpad But the specific topic is the same in my point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found quite simple way to forward using Charles idea:

```
    $fwd  = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
    $fwd->setBody($message->getContent());
    $h = $message->getHeaders();
    $h->removeHeader('To');
    $fwd->setHeaders($h);
    $fwd->addTo('email@example.com');
    $transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
    $transport->send($fwd);
```

Comment: Phew, glad that worked.  The Storage Message interface only *suggests* that the implementations of `getHeaders` and `getContent` return their data in a way that Mail Message natively understands.